# Entity Framework Dynamically Select Row & Columb

Tags: sql, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Does anyone know how I can select a row and column dynamically in EF4? (VB)

A bit like a map, I want to navigate through the data using x and y axis to pull out one fields value,

SQL would look like this

> SELECT " & MyColumbVariable & " FROM MyTable WHERE MyRow = " & MyVariable & "

Bit of a hack I know its not great. Perhaps there is a cleaner way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CreateQuery` method of object context. Assuming you are using 4.1+:

```
var result = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context)
            .ObjectContext.CreateQuery<Entity>(query);
```

If you're using 4.0 there's no need to cast to `IObjectContextAdapter` since your context is alreay of type `ObjectContext`.
Update:

You can also build expression trees yourself to build dynamic queries. It's a bit of work but you can use it everywhere by writing it in a generic way. A good sample has been explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2009/02/06/dynamic-expression-trees.aspx). Also search for Dynamic Queries/Building expression trees in Entity Framework  and you'll find some good tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to be very straight forward :(

I went through all my code to work with the data in a different way to get around this...